# Can we do spring security logout without POST

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I was referring to [this](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/) spring boot oauth guide. For logout functionality, the guide says:

> Spring security's `/logout` endpoint requires us to POST to it.

However I just added a react material UI button with href to `/logout` end point:

```
 <IconButton aria-label="logout" href="http://localhost:8080/logout" >
     <LogoutIcon sx={{color:"white"}}/>
 </IconButton>
```

and it started to work as desired (redirecting to login page on logout since I configured `HttpSecurity.logoutSuccessUrl` and redirect to google login if I try to hit any endpoint directly post logout).

Do I need to implement async POST request to `/logout` link using axios or am just fine with current implementation?

Comment: here you can read about the difference https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.7.0/servlet/authentication/logout.html `If CSRF protection is enabled (default), then the request must also be a POST.`

Comment: I'm curious whether or not you saw a logout confirmation page? Spring Security does require a POST for logout by default. Also by default `GET /logout` returns a confirmation page to help facilitate that.